# Ruby: Concise way to conditionally join strings with newlines?

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation

I need to add a `description` string to an existing `comments` variable, which contains either a string or *nil*. I want to separate the new description from any existing comments with a newline, but only if there *are* existing comments. I've come up with a couple ways that are kind of concise,

```
old_comments = comments + "\n" rescue ""
new_comments = old_comments + description
```

or

```
new_comments = [comments, description].compact.join("\n")
```

but I'm surprised there's not a less "tricky" way to squeeze this into a one-liner. Or is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[*comments, description].join($/)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is `$/`? Is it a kind of regex?

Comment: [comments, description].join($/) if comments

Comment: @ivan, It's a predefined global variable for the input record separator. (usually newline)

Comment: @mvidaurre I should've been more clear, but if `comments` was nil, I want `new_comments` to equal `description`, not nil.

Comment: Why try to be clever with `$/` when a simple `"\n"` would do?